# How can i get from git status "On branch master \n Nothing to commit.." to "On branch master \n Your branch is up to date \n Nothing to .." ?"

Tags: php, linux, git

I am building a PHP application which controls a git repository. I have a sync function which executes the command git status and while "Your branch is up to date" is not returned, takes necessary actions like remote or local branch may be ahead.

I also build the logic for if the local repo folder gets deleted then mkdir, chmod and git pull. To test it, i deleted the local repo folder and the new local repo is created and git pull is successful.

Now my logic is heavily dependent on the string "Your branch is up to date" but git status only returns "On branch master \n Nothing .." where previously the your branch string used to be between the two statements returned now.

I would like to ask how can i get from "On branch master \n Nothing.." to "On branch master \n your branch is up to date \n Nothing.." ?

I am using a PHP script to implement the above logic and use shell_exec() to execute git commands, collect output in a variable and use this->contains() to match status and act accordingly

```php
Sync()
{
    //If folder was deleted
    if(!is_dir($repo))
    {
        if(mkdir($repo))
        {
            shell_exec(chmod)
            shell_exec(git pull)
        }
    }

    //For rest of the cases
    $output = shell_exec("git status")
    while(!this->contains("Your branch is up to date", $output))
    {
        //Take necessary actions
    }
}
```

Comment: I would highly recommend using the libgit2 bindings in PHP, https://github.com/garvins/php-git, instead of `shell_exec`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for this. I wasn't aware of this when i started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I used the below command to resolve my issue:

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master